# How to Replace Icing Sugar in a No-Bake Cheesecake

Tags: sugar, honey, cheesecake

Are there any good substitutes for sugar in Cheesecakes? I am not interested in synthetic sugar like Aspartame. I want to use natural sugar substitute like honey. But if mix honey into the cheese (e.g: Philadelphia cheese), will it ruin the cheese cake. I don't mind getting the honey taste in the cake, but will I get the same consistency in the cheese compare to if I mix sugar into the cheese?

This is the recipe. I got it from www.recipify.com:

250 gr of digestive biscuit/biscotti

80 gr butter

80 gr Philadelphia cheese

5 table spoon of Nutella

4 tablespoon of icing sugar

400 gr of creme

1. Melt the butter in the sauce pan.
2. Crumble the biscuit, and pour the melted button onto it. Cool it in the fridge for half an hour.
3. Mix the Philadelphia cheese with the icing sugar. Once you have done that, mix the Nutella.
4. Whisk the creme. Combine it with Nutella and Philadelphia mixture.
5. Put everything onto the crumbed biscuit. Leave it in the fridge overnight.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking because you eat a Primal/Paleo style diet? If so, it may be worth mentioning as it will influence the answers. The answer suggesting barley malt for example would not be acceptable, as barley contains gluten which the Primal/Paleo diet excludes (just as they exclude processed sugars in favor of natural foods like honey). This information will be useful in helping people up- and down-vote the answers accordingly.

Comment: Ok...tbats a whole other thing from 'cheesecake'...no bake stuff is much more forgiving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you make cheesecake with honey instead of sugar? [Sure!](http://www.theprimalist.com/crustless-primal-cheesecake/)

Is it as simple as just replacing it 1:1? Not quite, there's increased moisture, but check the top answer [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1350/when-baking-what-works-well-as-a-sugar-substitute).

You'll need to reduce any liquid you might be adding a bit.  Without seeing your exact recipe, I can't give you an exact answer there.

---

Whoa. Whoa. Whoa....thats not cheesecake, thats no-bake 'cheesecake'. And that's not normal sugar, that's *icing* sugar.

No bake 'cheesecake' is *much* more forgiving about the ingredients - you'd not trying to set a custard like, you just want a thick, flavored, semi-firm pie filling.  Add the honey, but leave off a touch of the creme, maybe 20-30 g overall?  Icing sugar will actually thicken it a bit as its not only *not* a liquid, but its also got cornstarch in it.  There's about 1/4 tsp of cornstarch in that much icing sugar, so I'd add that.  If you're against cornstarch, I don't think it'd be the end of the world to leave it off.

I'd add the honey and then add 350 g of creme and see how the consistency is. You'll probably end up adding another 20g or so, but I'd wait and see.

Comment: thanks for the tip. So let me summarize what you are saying from my own understanding - just to make sure I get it right. I should mix (or whisk ?) the Philadelphia cheese with 20 - 30 g of honey and 1/4 table spoon (or did you mean tea spoon) of corn starch. I should put it in more creme. Instead of 400, I should put 450 or 470 depending on the consistency of the mixture.

Comment: @zfranciscus eek no, sorry, i mis typed on the creme, see my edit!

Comment: tsp = teaspoon, not tablespoon

Comment: thanks for the edit. One observation that I made from your edit is that, reducing the amount of creme will make the cake firmer - less liquid means a more consistent cake. To make things simpler why don't I just ditch the creme all together. What do you think about the purpose of the creme in this recipe? Is it more for taste ? Or is it an agent to soften the Nutella and the Philadelphia cheese mixture?

Comment: @zfranciscus if you ditch the creme it will be *very* firm, not to mention there will be much less of your mixture

Answer (score 0):

The best replacement of sugar is malt. For cakes, I prefer corn malt (or barley malt). We no longer use honey in cakes. With honey also, if you heat it up to more than 50 C it will loose some nutritional value ([some say even 37 C](http://www.chacha.com/question/what-happens-if-i-heat-up-honey)).

Answer (score -2):

I make 'no bake' Baileys and Chocolate Cheesecake never use the icing sugar - always works for me

Comment: Welcome to SA! Is your recipe similar to this one? If not, knowing that it "works for you" in this one recipe isn't necessarily very helpful. Please include some information about your recipe and how it is similar to the one in the question.

Comment: I'm going to leave this; I think it's an answer but not necessarily a very useful one, for the reasons Catija mentioned.