# How to Make Nutella Icing without Powdered Sugar

Tags: sugar, cheesecake

I received so many good tips on how to make a sugarless no-bake cheesecake:
[How to Replace Icing Sugar in a No-Bake Cheesecake](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/18419/how-to-replace-icing-sugar-in-a-no-bake-cheesecake)

As a final touch I want to put Nutella frosting on top of the cake. A layer of Nutella will be amazing, and it really complement the basic recipe. But nutella is very thick, and rigid. Spreading it on top of cheesecake will be tough, and I thought why not change it into an icing ! I found a number of recipe to do this, but they all involve powdered sugar. For example (I got this from http://juliatylerfoodblog.wordpress.com/2010/05/29/nutella-frosting/):

Ingredients:

3/4 c butter, softened

1/4 Nutella

1 tsp vanilla

1 Tbs milk

3 c powdered sugar

Blend all ingredients in a bowl until smooth. Adjust consistency by adjusting with a little more milk if too stiff, or a little more powdered sugar if too runny.

Can I still make a frosting out of this recipe without a powder sugar?

Comment: What about heating it up to reduce viscosity? Just use it full strength..

Comment: Are you avoiding powdered sugar from the store here, or sugar at all again?  Running normal sugar through a food processor + a lil cornstarch is powdered sugar.

Comment: @rfusca thank you for the info. I am trying to avoid sugar at all again.

Comment: @Ray I tried heating the nutella. It still very rigid, and hard to spread =(

Comment: Have you tried to beat the nutella? I would think that incorporating air into it would make it very spreadable. God knows there's already enough sugar in that stuff. You wouldn't end up with the same color, it would obviously be a lighter shade. I must admit, when spreading that stuff on my kid's toast on a Saturday morning, I have wondered if you could beat that stuff and use it in that way.

Comment: You can't really be avoiding sugar *and* using Nutella.  The first listed ingredient *is* sugar.

Answer (score 6):

A simple alternative would be to make a ganache flavored with Frangelico or another hazelnut liqueur. This has the advantage of having much less sugar, and probably better overall flavor, than an even-more-sweetened Nutella, assuming you start with a reasonably dark chocolate. All you do is boil cream, and pour it over a similar quantity by weight of chopped chocolate, into which you've added a healthy splash of hazelnut liqueur (or the liqueur can go into the cream as you bring it to a boil; either way works in my experience). Then stir vigorously until all the chocolate is smoothed out. You can pour it over while the mixture is still moderately warm and refrigerate it with the cheesecake. It will not be Nutella, but from experience it will be good, and evoke the same basic flavors.

Alternatively, most cheesecakes I am familiar with aren't topped with an icing, but a mixture of say cream or sour cream and other ingredients, sometimes added in the last few minutes of baking. These usually spread out reasonably well. You could consider softening the nutella in the microwave and mixing with a bit of cream, which will be a sort of less heavy ganache.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll give it a try and post the result here

Comment: Making ganache requires heating though. Do we want to keep with the theme of "no bake"?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making an almost mouse out of it by heating then folding into whipped cream or going more with just adding some cream and whipping together.